# Installation of latest MySql server

Tags: mysql, installation

I have downloaded the MySql 5.6.11 win32 version.

Facing problem in installing this downloaded version.

I cant find any setup file.

I am new to this please help me to install MySql server on my Windows 7 machine.

Download link : [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that this question is not really for StackOverflow and will be closed very soon. I'd recommend to ask it at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for this question you may get lots of -1 s. I don’t understand why this question itself exist. Anyway this is the link [mysql 5.6.11 windows msi installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html). Download big sized(170.6M) installer for offline installing that will save your bandwidth. If you have problem after downloading msi file then your windows installer or some other configuration may have problem.

Comment: ok thanks i am downloading that installer..
one more question.. how to remove this question before i get lots of "-1"s ?

Comment: This question also will get more -1 s. Open your eye and look at  the end of the question your will delete question.